# touch action of UIActionSheet not works fine

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

[image]

I found in my ipod touch and in iphone simulator, the button "return" only respond when touch area inside red rectangle, other places not respond
What's the problem?

Comment: Paste the code you use to set up the UIActionSheet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a tabbar controller?
The problem is that you are calling actionsheet in a subview and it's not fullscreen.
I had the same problem and I found the solution in this answer:

[iphone - weird bug between UIActionSheet and UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096852/iphone-weird-bug-between-uiactionsheet-and-uitabbar)

```
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your actionsheet.

its by default you have to push at upper side